# Prevent redirecting after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

It's probably a bad idea to ask a question, which already have multiple answers and multiple times, but I should ask it anyway. I tried pretty much everything I find there [Prevent redirect after form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038567/prevent-redirect-after-form-is-submitted) but nothing helps me.
There is a some minor detail, which I don't see. I'm not very familiar with jQuery and AJAX. Especially with the former.
So, the code:

```
<form id="form" action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ><!--action="uploadfile.php" onsubmit="return false;" -->
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" onblur="checkUsername(this.value)" onkeypress="clearError('nameerror')" oninput="clearError('nameerror')" /><br>
    <label id="nameerror"></label><br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" onblur="validateEmail(this.value)" onkeypress="clearError('emailerror')"/><br>
    <label id="emailerror"></label><br>
    Select a file<br />
    <label id="draganddroperror"></label><br>
    <input name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" type="file" onchange="onChange(event)" multiple /><br />
    <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="sendData()"  style="background-color: gray; color: #ffffff;" />Отправить</button>
</form>
```

There is my JS

```
function sendData() {
    var file_data = $("#fileToUpload").prop("files");
    console.log(file_data);
    if ($("#file_data").val() != "") {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        //form_data.append('file', file_data);
        //console.log(file);
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadfile.php', // point to server-side PHP script
            dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                // get server responce here
                //alert(data);
                // clear file field
                //$("#your-files").val("");
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false; //event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert("Please select file!");
    }
}
```

So, this is the code in question. All works flawlessly, except redirect. Another questions contains submit, but I didn't have submit input. I tried to delink form from post method (1st line), but I got server error. Return false everywhere.
I spent countless hours on this question, it consumed almost all my night hours for a few days. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your `return false` be after the `else` clause?

Comment: I don't think so. else clause don't post anything.

Comment: The click event of the `<button>` is a `post` action by itself.

Comment: I don't think you understand why you would return false. You basically haven't tried anything in that post you referenced. I don't see you preventing  the default action on the event (that you didn't bother to pass in to the click handler). I don't see you returning false to prevent the default action either.

Comment: When you don't have `<button type="submit"></button>` inside your form, every button acts as `type="submit"`

Comment: preventDefault - tried, then nothing post at all. It wasn't in code or in comments . "return false" originally weren't in my code. Tried to delete action from Form title, got server error.

Comment: Are you able to put the button outside of the form? That way, I believe it won't trigger the submit action. @WashingtonGuedes is right.

Comment: @GordonKushner moved button outside the form. Still got redirect

Comment: you can find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to prevent form submission is `return false` onsubmit as below:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return sendData()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--action="uploadfile.php" onsubmit="return false;" -->
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" onblur="checkUsername(this.value)" onkeypress="clearError('nameerror')" oninput="clearError('nameerror')" />
    <br>
    <label id="nameerror"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" onblur="validateEmail(this.value)" onkeypress="clearError('emailerror')" />
    <br>
    <label id="emailerror"></label>
    <br> Select a file
    <br />
    <label id="draganddroperror"></label>
    <br>
    <input name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" type="file" onchange="onChange(event)" multiple />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" style="background-color: gray; color: #ffffff;">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Note that I have written `onsubmit=return sendData()`. When the `sendData()` will return `true` the form will get submitted, otherwise it will never get submitted. For that the last statement in `sendData()` is `return false;`. In this way the form never gets submitted in current window, instead only Ajax submit works.

```
function sendData() {
  var file_data = $("#fileToUpload").prop("files");
  console.log(file_data);
  if ($("#file_data").val()) {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    //form_data.append('file', file_data);
    //console.log(file);
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    console.log(form_data);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'uploadfile.php', // point to server-side PHP script
      dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data) {
        // get server responce here
        //alert(data);
        // clear file field
        //$("#your-files").val("");
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please select file!");
  }
  return false;
}
```

I hope this gives you the clear understanding.

Comment: I accept your answer, because it's clear for understanding and simple for reproduce. Though, I should notice, that with that combination of my JS, your code and my PHP code on a backend it breaks the backend program. Somehow it sends to PHP empty sctructures and while I get from PHP some alerts, program the backend doesn't work as it meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

In function sendData() you should pass event param like this

```
 function sendData(evt) {

 }
```

and then in this function we should add `evt.preventDefault();` to stop submit action. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to cancel the default event handler for the submit event that the button triggers. To do this you need access to the event itself. It's best practice to handle the button click from JavaScript entirely instead of calling functions from HTML.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
submitButton.addEventListener('click', sendData);

// Then you will have access to the event in the sendData function
function sendData(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

[Live example](https://codepen.io/nielsdB97/pen/KZjOQZ)

A slightly cleaner approach is to handle the form submitting, however this is done. This would also catch a form submit by hitting the *enter* key for example.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', sendData);
```

[Live example](https://codepen.io/nielsdB97/pen/LeKwJP)

Comment: got an error: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined on  ev.preventDefault(); line

Comment: Did you remove the HTML `onclick` attribute and add the provided Javascript code?

Comment: Removed. Not it doesn't post, though there no errors in console. Added <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" style="background-color: gray; color: #ffffff;"  value="Send files" />
 <button id="btnSubmit2"   style="background-color: gray; color: #ffffff;" />Отправить</button> to handle form.

Comment: My Codepen example is working just fine, so I don't know what is going wrong on your end.. You could make a codepen with the code you currently have so I could try to find your mistake.

Comment: It doesn't work  for me neither on codepen neither locally. Don't fire any console.log (I opened console) messages or alerts().  Probably I just to tired. On both codepens (button click on the first, enter presskey on the second).

Answer (score 0):

Add type attribute with the value of `button` and you are done:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" ...
```

By default The value for the type attribute is `submit`, which tells the browser to submit the from to the server, If you change it to `button` the browser will do nothing, you can only bind events when the button is clicked