# click and mousedown events don't work on Ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Simple Ajax popup with a form collecting 3 fields of data, and a submit button. I can't programatically trigger the submit button though.

```
jQuery('#FormSubmit').click()
```

doesn't work. Neither does

```
jQuery('#FormSubmit').mousedown()
```

nor

```
document.getElementById("FormSubmit").click();
```

A real mouse click on the button works, but programmatically triggering it doesn't. It either posts the form in a non-AJAX way (page reload with post data appended to the url) or does nothing.

Anyone know the reasons why?
Is there something specific to Ajax to prevent this?

Edit:
Just tested triggering the submit event on the form instead, and that also posts the form in a non-AJAX way.

Comment: Form submission works using `submit()` function of form as https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Please post the rest of the JS and the Html. There isn't enough here to make sense of it.

Comment: Just make sure the submit function returns `false` as in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454059/4148965 to prevent window level form submit

Comment: @KamalSingh I was just trying that as you added your comment. It doesn't work correctly as it still posts the form non- AJAX with a page reload and appended url

Comment: For that I added another comment, so that form submit can be prevented in window. Hope that helps

Comment: Post your html and existing js code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use submit, or if you want you can write something like this:

```
`$('#formSubmit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input1 = $('#someInput1').val().trim();
    var input2 = $('#someInput2').val().trim();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'someUrl',
       type: 'POST',
       success: function (result) {
         //do something with the result
       }
    })
})`
```

Comment: The event.preventDefault() stops the default behavior of the form submit button.  Namely, it's default behavior is to submit the form and reload the page.  Adding the prevent default will stop that and allow your ajax call to work

Answer (score 0):

try to use `trigger`, like this

```
jQuery('#FormSubmit').trigger("click");
```